# Nested scrolls: nightmare

Tags: flutter

I'm providing you with a simplification/sample of my code so that you can reproduce it. I've used these packages: [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) and [expandable_page_view](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_page_view). Thank you.

---

I use a `NestedScrollView` to have a bar that hides when I scroll down. Then, I have a [`CarouselSlider`](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) displaying many `CustomScrollView`. The problem comes from the [`ExpandablePageView`](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_page_view): when I press it and scroll down, nothing happens (but anywhere works).

If `AbsorbPointer` wraps `ExpandablePageView`, it works but I don't want to use it.

Maybe the solution is to use one more `NestedScrollView` instead of `CustomScrollView` but this leads to problems with the behavior of my bar.

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:expandable_page_view/expandable_page_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Asuppr extends StatefulWidget {
  const Asuppr({super.key});

  @override
  State<Asuppr> createState() => _AsupprState();
}

class _AsupprState extends State<Asuppr> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                body: NestedScrollView(
                    floatHeaderSlivers: true,
                    headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
                          SliverAppBar(
                              expandedHeight: 80,
                              collapsedHeight: 80,
                              floating: true,
                              flexibleSpace: PreferredSize(
                                  preferredSize: Size(
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 80),
                                  child: Container(color: Colors.red)))
                        ],
                    body: CarouselSlider(
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          scrollPhysics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                          enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                          viewportFraction: 1,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        ),
                        items: [
                          CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
                            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                                child: Container(
                              height: 100,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            )),
                            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                                child: ExpandablePageView(children: [
                              GridView.count(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                                  children: List.generate(
                                      3,
                                      (index) => Container(
                                            color: Colors.green,
                                          )))
                            ])),
                          ])
                        ])))));
  }
}
```